# Jinja2 - Problem while looping a dictionary that uses hexadecimal numbers as key

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jinja2

I'm trying to loop over the following python dictionary using Jinja2 a 'for loop'

```
eg. {'0x1007c': '1'}.
```

However Jinja complains about the hex value. Any ideas how can I fix it ?

I tried to escape the value but I'm not sure if this is the right way to fix the problem.

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Devices</h1>
    <ul class="list.group">
        {% for device in devices %}
            <li class="list.group">{{ device.0x1007c }}</li> 
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

The error message that I'm receiving is this:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print
>   statement', got 'x1007c'

I was expecting retrieve the value 1.

Comment: If `device` is `dict`, I think it should be `{{device['0x1007c']}}`. If `devices` is `dict`, then `device` is the key, so it should be `{{devices[device]}}`

Answer (score 0):

If `devices` is a `list` and its each element `device` is a `dict`, then it should be `{{device['0x1007c']}}`.

If `devices` is `dict`, then `device` is the key, so it should be `{{devices[device]}}`.